# I am facing 'HTTP_GET' conflicts with a previous declaration error with the WifiManager lib, when i tried to include in my up and running code

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266

This is my header file

```
#include <DNSServer.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <WiFiManager.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>
#include <ESP8266mDNS.h>
#include <ArduinoOTA.h>
#include <ESPAsyncTCP.h>
#include <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h> 
#include <dds238.h>
```

I am using ESPAsyncWebServer.h for the jsonrequest to send the data to my ip.
and i am using WifiManger to automate the wifi connection so i do not need to hardocode the wifi credentials, however for this i have to use ESP8266WebServer.h along with WiFiManager.h. I am stuck in this for over one week.
The error i am getting:

```
In file included from src\main.cpp:31:
.pio\libdeps\esp12e\ESPAsyncWebServer-esphome\src/ESPAsyncWebServer.h:62:18: error: 'HTTP_GET' conflicts with a previous declaration
   62 |   HTTP_GET     = 0b00000001,
```

Comment: Please post the full error message. It will have additional information saying where the conflicting declaration is. However, if these are both in libraries you are including it will not be easy to solve. It is on the library writers if they do not use namespaces for their libraries with sufficiently unique names.

Comment: Maybe split your code intotwo files:  the part that deals with WiFiManager and the part that deals with the rest.  That way you don't have to include so many headers.

Comment: @user17732522 yeah i have to refactor my whole code. Now it is working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to provide in your sketch the includes for libraries used by other libraries. The WiFiManager library includes its dependencies and the Arduino build system will detect the libraries.

Remove `#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>` to avoid the conflict with the HTTP_GET enum value from ESP8266WebServer library.

Comment: i had to use this lib also to send my data over an port. However, i have resolved my issue by refreacing my code from scratch. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MAK I doubt you send data with a web server

Answer (score 0):

> I am facing some issue with the WifiManager lib, when i tried to include in my up and running code

I faced the same problem when develop ESP8266, the problem's key point is, `WiFiManager` and `ESPAsyncWebServer` have same `WebRequestMethod` macro, and the good news is `ESPAsyncWebServer` has defined `WEBSERVER_H` conditional compilation macro like this.

```
#ifndef WEBSERVER_H
typedef enum {
  HTTP_GET     = 0b00000001,
  HTTP_POST    = 0b00000010,
  HTTP_DELETE  = 0b00000100,
  HTTP_PUT     = 0b00001000,
  HTTP_PATCH   = 0b00010000,
  HTTP_HEAD    = 0b00100000,
  HTTP_OPTIONS = 0b01000000,
  HTTP_ANY     = 0b01111111,
} WebRequestMethod;
#endif
```

So, you just need to define `WEBSERVER_H` before include `ESPAsyncWebServer.h`, and the conflict problem will not happen.

```
#include <WiFiManager.h>
WiFiManager wifiManager;

#define WEBSERVER_H
#include <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>
```